# Wicket: Where to add components? Constructor? Or onBeforeRender?

Tags: java, wicket

I'm a Wicket newb.  This may just be my ignorance of the Wicket lifecycle so please enlighten me!  My understanding is that Wicket `WebPage` objects are instantiated once and then serialized.  This has led to a point of confusion for me, see below.

Currently I have a template class which I intend to subclass.  I followed the example in the Wicket docs demonstrating how to override the template's behavior in the subclass:

```
protected void onBeforeRender() {
        add(new Label("title", getTitle()));

        super.onBeforeRender();
}

protected String getTitle() {
        return "template";
}
```

Subclass:

```
protected String getTitle() {
        return "Home";
}
```

This works very well.  What's not clear to me are the "best practices" for this.  It seems like `onBeforeRender()` is called on every request for the page, no?  This seems like there would be substantially more processing done on a page if everything is in `onBeforeRender()`.  I could easily follow the example of the other Wicket examples and add some components in the constructor that I do not want to override, but then I've divided by component logic into two places, something I'm hesitant to do.

If I add a component that I intend to be in all subclasses, should I add it to the constructor or `onBeforeRender()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For components that are not a `Page`, you can override the new `onInitialize` callback to add components, which is only called once after construction, when the component has been added to the page (so that `component.getPage()` doesn't return `null`).

Another option is to use `addOrReplace()` instead of `add`.

As for calling overridden methods in a constructor, try to do that in a `Model` or some other delayed callback. In your example the solution is much simpler:

```
public abstract class BasePage extends WebPage {
    public BasePage() {
        add(new Label("title", new PropertyModel<String>(this, "title")));
    }
    public abstract String getTitle();
}
```

Using a `PropertyModel` to retrieve the contents of the label is much better than pushing the value into the label.

Answer (score 5):

You should add components in the constructor as a rule to which there are very few exceptions. Roughly, there is a phase for setting up the hierarchy (construction), and a separate phase for rendering it. It is not recommended (and often prohibited) to mix the two.

Comment: Thanks.  But if I can't mix the two, what is the recommended way to override template behavior?  Calling overriden methods in a constructor is bad practice.

Comment: That would be an exception then :-)

Answer (score -1):

onBeforeRender method is useful to handle the component's visible option or the model's management.

Comment: better use onConfigure() callback for this needs