# Wicket and the 'constructor calls overridable method' PMD warning

Tags: java, oop, wicket, pmd

We've been avoiding this PMD warning by moving most of our constructor code into `onInitialize()`. But are we just moving the problem (design flaw?) into a difference place?

i.e. is our `onInitialize()` just a surrogate constructor, that isn't noticed by PMD?

We are having problems of the sort that pop up when you call overridable methods in a constructor, but that seems to stem from the fact that Wicket itself calls one (can't find the exact source line, but `onInitialize()`, an overridable method, ends up getting called when you call `add()` in a constructor).

Happy to provide sample code if it'll help.

```
public class PageA extends WebPage {

    protected SomeBean bean;

    public PageA() {
        add(new Label("foo", "bar"));
        bean = new SomeBean();
    }

}

public class PageB extends PageA {

    public PageB() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInitialize() {
        add(new Label("rofl", bean.getSomeText()));
    }
}
```

You would expect this to be fine but the call to `onInitialize` does not happen where you may think it does:

When calling `add()` on a page the method flow is:

```
MarkupContainer    add()    
MarkupContainer    addedComponent() 
Page               componentAdded()
MarkupContainer    initialize()
Component          fireInitialize()
Component          onInitialize()
```

So as you can see if you add a component to a `WebPage` the `onInitialize()` method is fired, which is an overridable method leading to instances of the above looking sane code creating `NullPointerException`s.

The only warning you get that this may happen is the JavaDoc of `onInitialize()`:

> > NOTE:The timing of this call is not precise, the contract is that it is called sometime  before {@link Component#onBeforeRender()}.

Comment: Yes, to me it sounds like a design flaw. Its good to provide some concrete thing, nonetheless.

Comment: Also look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914151

Comment: If you peruse the Wicket forums (http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/VOTE-WICKET-3218-Component-onInitialize-is-broken-for-Pages-tc3341090.html#none), you'll see that this is a recognized and debated issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only add components to a container from inside its `onInitialized()` method, this problem won't arise. But it can't be verified by PMD, at least not by the built-in rules.

I don't think it's a design *flaw*, though. It's a design *decision*. You just can't base all your design on static analysis tools and predefined rules. API usability is also an important aspect of design, sometimes even more relevant than design principles.

For example, the [CQS (Command-Query Separation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation) principle would mandate that a method that *does* something (changes state) should not return anything, and methods that *return* something shouldn't have any side effects (change state).

If this was a hard rule, fluent interfaces (methods that change the object's state, and return `this`, allowing method chaining) couldn't be implemented. Wicket uses it extensively (almost all component manipulation methods return `this`), and this is one of the things that makes it a joy to use.

PMD is a very useful tool. But you must be the tool's master, not its slave. You should consider its warnings as possible issues, but if you are confident of your design choices, just mark the code to be bypassed and be happy.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following class:

```
public class A {

    public A() {
        System.out.println(val().toString());
    }

    protected Integer val() {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

It looks fine at first sight, assume `val()` should never return `null`, which is the case. Now `B` subclasses `A`:

```
public class B extends A {

    private final Integer i;

    public B() {
        //super();    //implicit
        i = 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer val() {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Class `B` is fine at first sight as well - it returns `i` from `val()` which is never `null` since it's `final` at it is initialized in constructor. However creating `B` instance will throw `NullPointerException`. Can you see why? *Hint*: look where implicit `super()` takes place.

Do you think moving `i` initialization will help? Why not?

```
private final Integer i = 1;
```

As a rule of thumb, never call non-private methods from constructor of non-final class. In fact I would even trigger compilation error in this case. As you can see this problem has nothing to do with Wicket and moving initialization to `onInitialize()` is to avoid such traps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and helpful link in the comments, but I already understand why calling overridable methods in a constructor is bad. I'm trying to work out whether chained onInitialize calls can cause the same problems.

Comment: Of course, moving it out to a separate method violates another principle, namely that after construction your object must always be in a consistent state and its methods must be callable in any order without it failing.

Answer (score 0):

> We are having problems of the sort that pop up when you call overridable methods in a constructor, but that seems to stem from the fact that Wicket itself calls one (can't find the exact source line, but onInitialize(), an overridable method, ends up getting called when you call add() in a constructor).

I'm pretty sure the `onInitialize()` method that's called when you call `add(component)` is the `onInitialize()` method of the component being added (the argument to the add method) and not of the class you're currently constructing.  This should be fine, as that component has already been completely constructed.

Comment: Please see sample code to see how you can get `onInitialized` fired after calling `add`.